# How to scroll to top of element with padding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

We have a horizontal jump menu that will navigate someone to the top of the `<h3 class="heading">` tags based on the menu item's `href`. For some reason, when someone clicks on the menu item, the page navigates to the top of the `<h3>` element rather than the top of the element (which includes `padding`).

**Question:**

- How would I navigate to the top of an element that has `padding` within it?

Current Issue:

[image: issue with jump menu]

Desired results:

[image: desired results jump]

Code

- Can also be found on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/xMLRrm).

```js
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.menu').addClass('menu--fixed');
  });
 $('.menu li a').on('click', function(evt) {
  var menuHeight = $('.menu').outerHeight(true);
  var elementOffset = ($(this).offset().top) - (menuHeight);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: elementOffset
  }, 2000);
  evt.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

```css
.container {
 max-width: 480px;
}
.heading {
 padding: 32px;
 background-color: #eee;
}
ul {
 list-style: none;
}
.menu {
 position: relative;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-between: space-between;
 
}
.menu li {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
}

.menu a {
 color: white;
 padding: 32px;
}

.menu--fixed {
 position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="menu__wrapper">
<ul class="menu">
 <li><a href="#el1">element 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#el2">element 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#el3">element 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
 <h3 class="heading" id="el1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</h3>
 <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet.</p>


<p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta del veritas.</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
 <h3 class="heading" id="el2">A Guide to Solving Web Development Problems</h3>
 <p>Epicurus autem, in quibus sequitur Democritum, noil fere labitur, Quam- quam utriusque cum mutta non prolx). turn illiid in priniis, quoJ, cum in rerum nalura duo quaerenda sint, ununi quae materia sit ex qua quaeque res cfficiatur, alterum quae vis sit quae quidque efficiat, de materia disserucrunt, vim et causam efficiendi reliquerunt. Sed lioc commune vitiuni; illae Epicur propriae ruinae: censet enim eadem ilia indlvidua e solida corpora ferri deorsum suo pondere ad lineam i hunc naturalem esse omnium corporum motuni.</p>

<p>Deinde ibidem homo acutus, cam illud occorreret, j omnia deorsum e regione ferrentur et, ut dixi, ad lineam, numquam fore ut atomus altera alteram posset attingere, itaque attulit rem commenticiam.</p>

<p>Declinare dixit atomum perpaulum, quo nihil posset fieri minus; ita eifici complexiones et copulationes et adhaesiones atomorum inter se, ex quo eificeretur mundus omnesque partes mundi quaeque in eo essent. Quae cum res tota fieta sit piieriliter, turn ne efficit quidem^ quod vult. Nam et ipsa declinatio ad libidinem fiiigitur - ait enim deelinare atomum sine causa, quo nibil turpius physico quam fieri.</p>



<p>This is about how to solve technical problems that arise from using front or back end technologies to make web pages or apps but some of these steps will be applicable to solving technical problems in general.</p>

<p>Half the technical problems in development are caused by something trivial but for all the problems past this level, you'll probably need to do some structured thinking.</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
 <h3 class="heading" id="el3">Tempore intellegi convenire</h3>

<p>Qui autem alia matunt scribi a nobis, aequi esse debent, quod et seripta multa sunt, sic ut plura nemini e nostris, et scribentur fortasse plura et tamen qui diligenter haec quae de philosophia Htteris mandamus legere assueverit, iudicabit nulla ad legendum his esse potiora.</p>
<p>Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis dolor repellendus. Qua temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae pondere ad lineam. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</p>

</div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: What if you use anchor tags and target a div above the content?

Comment: @JakubMuda are you suggesting `var elementOffset = ($(this).parent().offset().top) - (menuHeight);` where i get the `parent()`? That did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see is that `this` in your click handling function is the link element in the menu, so getting the offset of it for your calculation has no relevance to the actual `<h3>` element you're trying to scroll to.

Also, why not always keep the menu fixed if that is the desired behavior on scrolling?  Changing it to fixed on the first scroll event changes the layout of the container and throws off the spacing.  In my example, I moved the menu outside of the container and made it permanently fixed. I then added padding to the top of the `.container` element to make it render below the fixed menu when scrollTop is 0 (at page load).

Then, I used the `href` attribute of the menu `<a>` element being clicked to find the `<h3>` element with that same id.  Using the actual `<h3>` element's offset for the calculation gives the desired result.

Check out my example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/bdoughty2018/pen/MLvJOd

Comment: changing the attribute to `position: fixed` on first scroll did the job!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a gap between the top of the page and your menu. You need to specific your top position when you use `position: fixed;`. 
If you want the menu to stick to the top, then use `top: 0px;`

Also, there is default margin-top on the menu, so you will need to remove that too.

```
.menu--fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

It should be much easier to play with values to cater for the menu height in Javascript after you have this in. (You will also need to remove the `margin-bottom` for this).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.menu').addClass('menu--fixed');
  });

  $('.menu a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get clicked anchor href.
    var anchorID = $(this).attr('href');
    // Get scroll position of the target location.
    var scrollDestination = $(anchorID).offset().top;
    // Cater for menu height
    var finalScroll = scrollDestination - 
$('.menu').outerHeight(true);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: finalScroll
    }, 2000);
  });  
});
```

Edit: Javascript.

Comment: after adding the `top`, it is still having an issue navigating. Any thoughts as to why that would be?

Comment: In your javascript, your not really specifying where your destination is; You're only specifying the position of your button and the menu height. That is the main reason it isn't going where you want it to be.

I have updated my answer with a small snippet which should get you what you want.